# Jquery date implement in several input groups

Tags: jquery, forms, date

I have this complex form. When i press green plus it generates similar form for more clients entry. I'am trying achieve that when select date darbo pradzia it automatically generates date for bandomasis laikotarpis. But if i generate more forms with green plus on other forms date counting doesn't work. Name of inputs the same but i need different values in them. for example:

```
1form - Darbo pradzia 2020/01/01 - Bandomasis laikotarpis 2020/04/01 (+3 months generated by script)
2form - Darbo pradzia 2020/03/01 - Bandomasis laikotarpis 2020/06/01 (+3 months generated by script)
3form - Darbo pradzia 2020/07/01 - Bandomasis laikotarpis 2020/10/01 (+3 months generated by script)
```

and so on. How can I achieve that? Inputs have the same name, but need different dates counted on the same script.

```js
$('#skaicius').val(2);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#duomenys').submit(function() {
    $('#skaicius').val($('.fieldGroup').length * 1 + 1);
  })
  //papildomu pareigu limitas
  var maxGroup = 10;
  //$('#skaicius').val(2);
  //papildomu pareigu pridejimas
  $(".prideti").click(function() {
    if ($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup) {
      var fieldHTML = '<div class="row form-group fieldGroup">' + $(".fieldGroupCopy").html() + '</div>';
      $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);

    } else {
      alert('Viršintas didžiausias papildomų pareigų skaičius.');
    }
  });


  $(document).on("change", ".form-check-input", function() {
    var inputklase = $(this).attr("name");
    console.log(inputklase);
    $(this).closest("div").find("input." + inputklase).val($(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0);

  })

  //papildomu pareigu salinimas
  $("body").on("click", ".salinti", function() {
    $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();

  });
  // limits pagrindines for one only checked
  $(document).on("change", ":checkbox[name=pagrindines1]", function() {
    var $ckb = $(":checkbox[name=pagrindines1]");
    var $checked = $ckb.filter(":checked");
    $ckb.not($checked).prop("disabled", $checked.length >= 1);
  });


  // Generates start and end date
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.darbo_pradzia').change(function() {
      let date = new Date($(this).val());
      let newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3));
      var day = ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
      var month = ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      var formatted = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
      $('.bandomasis_laikotarpis').val(formatted);
    });
  });
  //select option from padalinys 
  (function($) {
    $('.test2').on('blur', function(e) {
      let inputVal = $(this).val();

      $('.padalinys option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
          $(this).prop('selected', true);
        }
      })
    });
  })(jQuery);
  //select option from pareigos
  (function($) {
    $('#test3').on('blur', function(e) {
      let inputVal = $(this).val();

      $('.pareigos option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
          $(this).prop('selected', true);
        }
      })
    });
  })(jQuery);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row form-group fieldGroup">
    <h4>Darbuotojo pareigos</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-success prideti" title="[Pridėti pareigas]"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="kodas">Tabelio nr.</label>
      <input type="text" id="tabelis" name="tabelio_numeris[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="imone">Įmonė</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="imone[]">
        @foreach ($imones as $imone)
        <option value="{{$imone->id}}">{{$imone->pavadinimas}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="miestas">Miestas</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="miestas[]">
        @foreach($miestai as $miestas)
        <option value="{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}">{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pad. kodas</label>
      <input type="text" id="test2" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
      <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
        <option value="2">test - 2</option>
        <option value="3">test - 3</option>
        <option value="4">test - 4</option>
        <option value="5">test - 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pareigu kodas</label>
      <input type="text" id="test3" name="parkodas[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <label class="text-black" for="pareigos">Pareigos</label>
      <select class="form-control pareigos" name="pareigos[]">
        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
        <option value="2">test - 2</option>
        <option value="3">test - 3</option>
        <option value="4">test - 4</option>
        <option value="5">test - 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" >Darbo pradžia</label>
      <input type="date" name="darbo_pradzia" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
      <input type="date" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" for="terminuota_sutartis">Terminuota sutartis</label>
      <input type="date" id="terminuota_sutartis" name="terminuota_sutartis" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" for="atldata">Atleidimo data</label>
      <input type="date" id="atldata" name="atleidimo_data" class="form-control">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vadovas1" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input" value="1">
      <input class="vadovas1" type="hidden" name="vadovas[]" value="0">
      <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="vadovastxt">Vadovas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input pagrindines" value="1" name="pagrindines1">
      <input class="pagrindines1" type="hidden" name="pagrindines[]" value="0">
      <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="pagrindinestxt">Pagrindinės (Generuoti barkodą pagal šią kortelę.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Papildomos pareigos -->
  <div class="row form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <h4>Papildomos pareigos</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-danger salinti" title="[Šalinti]"><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="kodas">Tabelio nr.</label>
      <input type="text" id="tabelis" name="tabelio_numeris[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="imone">Įmonė</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="imone[]">
        @foreach ($imones as $imone)
        <option value="{{$imone->id}}">{{$imone->pavadinimas}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="miestas">Miestas</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="miestas[]">
        @foreach($miestai as $miestas)
        <option value="{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}">{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pad. kodas</label>
      <input type="text" id="test2" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
      <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
        <option value="2">test - 2</option>
        <option value="3">test - 3</option>
        <option value="4">test - 4</option>
        <option value="5">test - 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pareigu kodas</label>
      <input type="text" id="test2" name="parkodas[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <label class="text-black" for="pareigos">Pareigos</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="pareigos[]">
        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
        <option value="2">test - 2</option>
        <option value="3">test - 3</option>
        <option value="4">test - 4</option>
        <option value="5">test - 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" >Darbo pradžia</label>
      <input type="date"  name="darbo_pradzia" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
      <input type="date"  name="bandomasis_laikotarpis" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" for="terminuota_sutartis">Terminuota sutartis</label>
      <input type="date" id="terminuota_sutartis" name="terminuota_sutartis" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="text-black" for="atldata">Atleidimo data</label>
      <input type="date" id="atldata" name="atleidimo_data" class="form-control">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vadovas1" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input" value="1">
      <input class="vadovas1" type="hidden" name="vadovas[]" value="0">
      <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="vadovastxt">Vadovas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input pagrindines" name="pagrindines1">
      <input class="pagrindines1" type="hidden" name="pagrindines[]" value="0">
      <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="pagrindinestxt">Pagrindinės (Generuoti barkodą pagal šią kortelę.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Papildomos pareigos pabaiga -->

</div>
```

Comment: 1. You need UNIQUE IDs 2. If you have event handlers on dynamic data, you need to delegate - it seems you are delegating for some but not all and watch the IDs: `$('#test2').on('blur', function(e) {`

Comment: I cant;t delegate ids because other forms created dynamically and all values goes to array.

Comment: I do not understand what you wrote there. You cannot re-use testN ids - use class instead

Comment: changed. but problem where generating start and end date. It works only in first form. When i generate similar script doesn't work it not generate date.